# pointer initialization with template typename

Tags: c++, templates

I've got class that inherite from template class. I would like to initialize pointer with template argument. How can I do that?

Algorithm.h:

```
#ifndef ALGORITHM_H
#define ALGORITHM_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>

class Algorithm
{
protected:
    T data;
    T result;  //(*)
    int dataSize;
    int resultSize;
public:
    Algorithm(){}
    Algorithm(T in, int inSize){
        cout<<"Algorithm constructor!"<<endl;
        data = in;
        dataSize = inSize;
        resultSize = dataSize;
        result = new T;    //(**)
        for (int i = 0; i<this->resultSize; i++){
            this->result[i] = 0;
            cout<<"i: "<<i<<" *(this->result+i) = "<<this->result[i]<<endl;
        }
    }

#endif // ALGORITHM_H
```

Error is in (**) line:

> /home/user/Projects/Algorithms/algorithm.h:23: error: cannot
>   convert 'float**' to 'float*' in assignment
>            result = new T;
>                   ^

I could change line (*) but it is not my favourite solution as it will be inconsistent with data - I would rather that to be so. So how can I initialize it to feel all result table with 0s then?

Comment: If you have ``result = new T; ``, then the type of ``result`` must be ``T *``.

Comment: Presumably at least you meant `result = new T[resultSize]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to change the (*) line to `T* result`, then you can use [`std::remove_pointer<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer) type trait (C++11 or later)

```
result = new typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type(); // a single element value-initialized
```

or (if you want an array, which is probably what you want)

```
result = new typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type [resultSize]; // array of resultSize elements
```

Finally, you can even value-initialize your array as

```
result = new typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type [resultSize]{}; // value-initialized array
```

However I find this solution awkward (to say the least), and it is probably much more clear if you use `T* result` instead.